# Javascript get all input elements that contain values

Tags: javascript

I'm using the **querySelectorAll()** JS function to retrieve all elements under a datagrid table (aspx page) , that datagrid contains several checkboxes / textboxes , there's a save button which should only be enabled when the following rule is satisfied :

At least 1 checkbox needs to be checked **OR** at least one textbox needs to contain text ( not empty )

Is there a way to check if any of the **textbox** input elements returned by **querySelectorAll()** , has a value ?

```
function validate() {
            var search = document.getElementById("myGrdID").children;

            //var hasAnyText = search[0].querySelectorAll("input:valid");
            var hasAnyChecked = search[0].querySelectorAll("input:checked");

            console.log("Any check? " + hasAnyChecked.length);
        }
```

i'd like to avoid using Jquery , already managed to get all the checked input elements , couldn't find a way yet to find all the textboxes with values (any value not a specific string).

Comment: You can use a loop through the input elements and check their value:

    function checkInputs() {
        const inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    
        for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].value) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

checkInputs() will return true if at least one of the input fields is filled.
Alternatively, you can use `.checkValidity()` instead of `.value` to check the validity of the input field instead of it's value.

Comment: `const filled= search[0].querySelectorAll("input[type=text").fillter(inp => inp.value.trim()!==");`

Comment: @mplungjan I think you will have to use spread operator as nodeList is not exactly an array. `const textBoxes = search[0].querySelectorAll('.-textbox-selector-name'); const hasAnyEmptyText  = [...textBoxes].filter(input => input.value !== '');`

Comment: Yeah I think you are correct - just a quick comment from my mobile

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use the `filter` function ?

```
var results = hasAnyChecked.filter(input => input.value != null)
```

Edit : comment below me has a point, but if you use those kind of selectors you won't be able to check multiple scenarios :

```
var results = hasAnyChecked.filter(input => input.value !== null || input.value !== false) // Handles both text inputs and checkboxes
```

Comment: `input.value !== false` is not useful. try `input.value.trim()===""` instead

Comment: And OP was looking for textBoxes not checked checkboxes